# Failed to open JTAG cable

Tags: fpga, xilinx, spartan, xilinx-edk

I'm using an Atlys Spartan-6 xc6slx45 board. I am unable to burn the bit file using SDK. When I try to program FPGA it shows these errors:

> Program FPGA failed
>   Connection to Board Failed
>
> Failed to Open JTAG Cable
>       Cable target is not connected to the host

However I connected the 2 USB cables (one of the program and other of the adept USB port J17). Should I connect THE J10 also?

Comment: Try resetting everything, rebooting and reloading your jtag connection. I use Quartus II and I also have intermittent problem like losing the jtag connection having to reset my FPGA and the connection.

Comment: you just use the usb cables???

Comment: Have you tried solutions proposed [here](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Development-Tools/SDK-related-problem/td-p/219611)?

Comment: I read it before but my problem that I had only 2 cables when I got the board (2 usb cables)one of the program and the other of the uart.I don't have the JTAG cable.

Comment: I had resolved the problem

Comment: go to xilinx tools -->Jtag settings --> Jtag cable -->Digilent USB cable